# How to get Image name in java?

Tags: android, imageview

i want to get image name in android

for example,

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewByID(R.id.MyImage);

img.srcName() // it should return following android:src="@drawable/abc"
```

is it possible or not?
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: r u getting any error with this ? I dont think that there is any function like this in ImageView or is it thr ???

Comment: lol no .srcName() is not the method its dummy example i have given in this code to explain my problem what i need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible or not?

It is not possible. For starters, there may not be a resource involved in the `ImageView`, as images can come from many places.

Comment: is it possible for the imageButton?

Comment: @UMAR: No. ImageButton is just a subclass of ImageView.

Comment: actually, i am creating a rolling dice activity and for this after rolling dice i have to pick image name to give points to user for this i need to get name of the dice any idea what should i do?

Comment: and those images i am displaying in imageView with animation

Comment: @UMAR: You are the one calling `setImageResource()` to change the image as a result of the dice roll. You know at that point which image it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the name of the resource with this function:

```
getResources().getResourceName(resid);
```

But you need the resId for that.
Check the [Resources.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

Comment: it will work for the hardcoded images if i change images dynamically then?

Answer (score 0):

Try `getResourcesEntryName()` method

```java
getResources().getResourceEntryName(0x000000);
```